# How to select a different volume for /Users folder during installation of OS X

Tags: macos

Is it possible to specify that the `/Users` folder should be installed on a different volume during installation?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do it after installation?

Comment: Not really. Wanted to clean install Lion and was thinking if there's a way to choose a different location during installation.